# Android - need to draw a line with a cross in the middle

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view that has a seekbar and below the seek bar I want to display the minimum and maximum values with a line between them that has a small cross at the middle point. I have this in an XML layout apart from the line with cross. can I define the shape in XML or do I need to draw it at runtime?

**EDIT**

I used a 9-patch with a very small patch area to produce the following cross effect:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I have the correct visualisation in mind, but if the cross should always appear in the middle, then a 9-patch sounds like a sensible option. You could of course draw create/extend a view that does the drawing at runtime, but that will probably require a bit more work.

Comment: I do want the cross to be in the middle. I'll try the 9-patch. But I might have to go the drawing method.

Comment: Might be worth mocking up a quick example of what you're after. That way it'll be easier for others to help you out.

Comment: you can post a link to an image and some one will edit your question.

Comment: Link to i,agehttps://www.dropbox.com/s/tgj8kszqnv418cv/Cross.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a view in xml file with 1dp or 2dp height and put background color for this view then it become like a line

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@color/listColor" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/header_list_item_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<View 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/listtext"
  android:paddingTop="20dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
  android:visibility="invisible"
  android:id="@+id/lineView"
  android:background="@color/lineColor" />
<View 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/lineView"
  android:paddingTop="20dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
  android:background="@color/lineColor" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listtext"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lineView"
    style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```